# why can't I do a loop with `var output = document.getElementById('message').innerHTML;`

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, innerhtml

Please, would you be able to explain, why I can't do a loop, if I want to store 'innerHTML' in 'output' variable in the second example?: 'var output = document.getElementById('message').innerHTML;'

```
var x = 0;
var output = document.getElementById('message');
do {
  output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + x;
  x = x + 1;
}
while (x < 6);
------------------------------------------------------------                                                                
var x = 0;
var output = document.getElementById('message').innerHTML;
do {
  output = output + x;
  x = x + 1;
}
while (x < 6);
```

Comment: Both snippets work fine, but they do different things. The first one changes the content of an HTML element, the second one changes a string variable. But as of course, the HTML element and the string variable are totally unrelated, changing the string doesn't have any effect on the HTML element

Comment: I am confused what is wrong with the second example. What do you expect to get?

Comment: I expect to get `012345` like in the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are confused with why you can't add `innerHTML` to the `output` in `output = output +x`, but the first example you can. That is because the first example, the output should store something like`[object ...]`. So everytime, the `output.InnerHTML` will keep updating. For the second example, you have already set the `output` to the `innerHTML` of `message` and it has already become a string, not a `html`. So you can't use `innerHTML` to change anything. The `innerHTML only help to change the value of` html` tag and that is why the loop doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: hi Shawn. It's still weird. If I have: `document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = document.getElementById('message').innerHTML + x;` in the following example: `var x = 0; do { document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = document.getElementById('message').innerHTML + x; x = x + 1; } while(x < 6);`, the the loop will run.

Comment: `document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = document.getElementById('message').innerHTML + x;` and `output = output + x` seems to be the same, if `var output = document.getElementById('message').innerHTML`

Comment: @Chris, I just wonder are you confused with why you can't use `output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + x` in the second example or something else. I can't fully understand what you are confused with, so i don't how to help you

Comment: I can use `output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + x`. My problem is, that I don't understand, why I can't do a loop, if I want to use `var output = document.getElementById('message').innerHTML;` + `output = output + x;` @Shawn

Comment: @ Chris, Are you sure your other code is right? I just run the second example code and it return `012345`. i put the image in the question

Comment: hi @Shawn. yes, your answer makes sense :) I must add `console.log(output)`

Comment: @Chris, click accept the answer on the left if you think my answer help and have a nice day

Comment: thank you @Shawn. have a nice day too

Answer (score 0):

The loop works
but you can't add something like this
var output = document.getElementById('message').innerHTML;
output = output + x;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1nuE.png)

Comment: hi Mahdi. but that's my question: why I can't add 'innerHTML' to 'output' variable?

Comment: Because when you say document.getElementById('message').innerHTML you just have a normal string like let test = 'test' and you can't change something in UI (HTML)